# Python read specific value from text file and total sum

Tags: python

I have this text file, Masterlist.txt, which looks something like this:

```
S1234567A|Jan Lee|Ms|05/10/1990|Software Architect|IT Department|98785432|PartTime|3500
S1234567B|Feb Tan|Mr|10/12/1991|Corporate Recruiter|HR Corporate Admin|98766432|PartTime|1500
S1234567C|Mark Lim|Mr|15/07/1992|Benefit Specialist|HR Corporate Admin|98265432|PartTime|2900
S1234567D|Apr Tan|Ms|20/01/1996|Payroll Administrator|HR Corporate Admin|91765432|FullTime|1600
S1234567E|May Ng|Ms|25/05/1994|Training Coordinator|HR Corporate Admin|98767432|Hourly|1200
S1234567Y|Lea Law|Ms|11/07/1994|Corporate Recruiter|HR Corporate Admin|94445432|PartTime|1600
```

I want to reduce the Salary(the number at the end of each line) of each line, only if "PartTime" is in the line and after 1995, by 50%, and then add it up.

Currently I only know how to select only lines with "PartTime" in it, and my code looks like this:

```
f = open("Masterlist.txt", "r")
for x in f:
    if "FullTime" in x:
        print(x)
```

How do I extract the Salary and reduce by 50% + add it up only if the year is after 1995?

Comment: Add what up? Please post your expected output.

Comment: You have a "csv" file (separated by pipes instead of commas). Use the `csv` module or something like `pandas` to read the file. Then you can do any processing you want with the columns. "Implement this for me" is off-topic here. Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), 
and provide a [mre] asking about your _specific_ issue _after_ you have made an attempt at solving it.

Comment: A question - what do you mean by "reduce by 50% + add it up"? Is adding in the sense of uploading it to the original text file?

Comment: One more thing: I just noticed that in your text file there are no cases where somebody is with PartTime and >1995 attributes.

Comment: @not_speshal add the last value, which is salary

Comment: @ŽeljkoJelić what i mean is that if there is 'PartTime' in each line, I want to reduce the salary by 50%, and then add each salary together

Comment: @ŽeljkoJelić this is only a short portion of the text file, will be too long if I show the entire thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library.
From your question I suppose you want to reduce by 50% `Salary` if year is less than 1995, otherwise increase by 50%.

```py
import pandas as pd

path = r'../Masterlist.txt' # path to your .txt file

df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='|',  names = [0,1,2,'Date',4,5,6,'Type', 'Salary'], parse_dates=['Date']) 
# Now column Date is treated as datetime object 
print(df.head())

         0         1   2       Date                      4  \
0  S1234567A   Jan Lee  Ms 1990-05-10     Software Architect   
1  S1234567B   Feb Tan  Mr 1991-10-12    Corporate Recruiter   
2  S1234567C  Mark Lim  Mr 1992-07-15     Benefit Specialist   
3  S1234567D   Apr Tan  Ms 1996-01-20  Payroll Administrator   
4  S1234567E    May Ng  Ms 1994-05-25   Training Coordinator   

                    5         6    Type      Salary  
0       IT Department  98785432  PartTime    3500  
1  HR Corporate Admin  98766432  PartTime    1500  
2  HR Corporate Admin  98265432  PartTime    2900  
3  HR Corporate Admin  91765432  FullTime    1600  
4  HR Corporate Admin  98767432    Hourly    1200  

df.Salary = df.apply(lambda row: row.Salary*0.5 if row['Date'].year < 1995 and row['Type'] == 'PartTime' else row.Salary + (row.Salary*0.5 ), axis=1)

print(df.Salary.head())

0    1750.0
1     750.0
2    1450.0
3    2400.0
4     600.0
Name: Salary, dtype: float64
```

Add some modifications to the **if, else** statement inside the `apply` function if you wanted something different.

Comment: Is there another way beside using pandas?

Comment: There definitively is, but you should not avoid `pandas` library or using it, learning it even a bit will save you hours. Trust me on this one. If you don't have it installed open you command prompt (*cmd*)  and write `pip install pandas`.

Comment: Ok I currently able to see the results, but why is it only showing 5 lines, instead of the whole text file that I am using (which is more than 5 lines)

Comment: Also I want to sum up the values of those who's salary got affected and print it, how do I accomplish that as well?

Comment: 1) if I answered you question mind selecting my answer as the correct one? <br>
2) Look at the `print` statement, there is `head()` function. Remove it and you will get all the data 
3) You can loop through the the `df`, like
```python
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   if row[insert your condition here] & row[another condtion]:
      print(index) 
```

Comment: I dont understand what am I supposed to do, add this statement to df.apply or in a new line?